# class Matrix: AttributeError: Matrix instance has no attribute '__getitem__' in max(self, other) method

Tags: class, python-2.7, matrix

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, nr, nc):
        self.NRows = nr
        self.NCols = nc
        self.data = [ [0]*self.NCols for r in range(self.NRows) ]

    def max(self, other):
        """ return: a matrix with as many rows as the shorter of self and other and as many columns as the narrower of self and other. 
            Each entry of the returned matrix should be the larger (the max) of the corresponding entries in self and other. 
        """
        minrows = min(other.NRows, self.NRows)
        mincols = min(other.NCols, self.NCols)
        M = Matrix(minrows, mincols)
        for i in range(minrows):
            for j in range(mincols):
                M.data[i][j] = max(self.data[i][j], other[i][j])
        return M
```

This code give Traceback in max when tested and output said:

...in max

```
M.data[i][j] = max(self.data[i][j], other[i][j])
```

**AttributeError: Matrix instance has no attribute '__getitem__'**

How to get rid of this error? Where I made mistake?. Please help someone.

Comment: I'm assuming this is [tag:python]?

Comment: Yes, this code written in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this :

```
M.data[i][j] = max(self.data[i][j], other.data[i][j])
```

instead of

```
M.data[i][j] = max(self.data[i][j], other[i][j])
```